# Building an Array Based on Passed-in Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I'm working on a function where I check a value that is passed in, and then add it to an array. What I have isn't working, I just get an empty array:

```
let category = 'client';

function builtArray() {
  let catArray = [];
  if (category === 'client') {
    catArray.push('client');
  }
  console.log(catArray);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There nothing wrong in code, where are you invoking the function?

Comment: Works: https://jsfiddle.net/7vgvbfbt/

Comment: You probably logging the returned value of the function after you invoke it. (no return means `undefined`). So are you getting `undefined` or empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
let category = 'client';

function builtArray() {
  let catArray = [];
  if (category === 'client') {
    catArray.push('client');
  }
  console.log(catArray);
}
```

should be

```
let category = 'client';

function builtArray(cat) {
  let catArray = [];
  if (cat === 'client') {
    catArray.push(cat);
  }
  console.log(catArray); // => ['client']
}

builtArray(category);
```

1. You have to "invoke" the function for it to run. This means calling it with `()`, that's what I've done at the end.
2. You pass "category" in as an argument to the function, the function renames what you've passed in (as `cat`), it then checks to see if that variable is equal to the string `client`, if it is, it inserts it into `catArray`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was forgetting to actually call/invoke the function. Follow-up question, that gets closer to what I'm trying to do -- how could I continue to build the array as other values are passed in via 'category'? Specifically, I'm having users select checkboxes in a search filter list, and for each filter they select, I need to pass that category value into the array. And I also need it do de-select (splice, I assume) a category value when they de-select a checkbox.

Comment: So the second that the DOM is involved (via checkboxes, etc.) I have to ask if you're using native in-browser JS or a framework/DOM manipulation library. I'm happy to answer, there are just a million ways I could...

Comment: This is for an Angular 2 app I'm building. I have the search feature currently working where a radio box is selected, and the search results filter and re-generate based on that category. But now there's been a request for a user to be able to select multiple checkboxes and to re-generate results based on all of those categories. I assume I would do this with an array.

Comment: So... at first a user might select one filter -- I need to filter for that. And then they might select another filter category, and now I need to have both of those items, etc... And if they un-check a checkbox, I'd want to splice out that category from the array.

Comment: You can set the new array to `[...slice(0, index), slice(index)]` in order to remove the element and "`index`" from the array... beyond that, probably easier to answer via another question.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will craft a new question for the larger context of what I'm attempting.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you wish to keep the array after the function, in which case declare it outside the function.

```
let category = 'client';
let catArray = [];


function builtArray(str) {

    if (category === 'client') //this will only allow 'client' to be inserted
    {
    catArray.push(str);
  }
  console.log(catArray);
}
```

then call as desired:

```
builtArray('client');
```

Comment: You make a good point that I should declare the array outside of the function in order to have access to it outside the function scope. Thanks.